# 'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command in Windows even though I've added Java to the $PATH

Tags: java, windows, classpath

This is my first time coding on Windows, and I'm trying to compile Java like so:

`javac Main.java`

But I'm receiving the error `'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.` even though I have my Java in the classpath: If I type `echo %PATH%` I get

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Amazon\cfn-bootstrap\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_251\bin;` - notice the last path, it's a valid Java path.

How do I fix this?

Comment: You should add the path to JDK not the JRE, `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\bin;`

Comment: To state that correctly, you should add the JDK, not the JRE, to the PATH